# How to ignore escape character ?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

this is my string

```
$mystring = "INSERT INTO `glpi_networkports` (`entities_id`,`is_recursive`,`items_id`,`itemtype`,`comment`,`logical_number`,`name`,`networkinterfaces_id`,`ip`,`mac`,`netmask`,`gateway`,`subnet`,`netpoints_id`)"
```

How can i ignore escape ?

Because it gave me string like this :

```
INSERT INTO glpi_networkports (entities_id,is_recursive,items_id,itemtype,comment,logical_number,
ame,
etworkinterfaces_id,ip,mac,
etmask,gateway,subnet,
etpoints_id)
```

Thanks

Comment: What you mean by "ignore"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use quote or double the escape char:

```
$mystring = "INSERT INTO 'glpi_networkports' ..."
$mystring = "INSERT INTO ``glpi_networkports`` ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Currently your select statement is changed because you used a double quoted string and `n is expanded to a new line, turning the select to an invalid statement.

Use single quotes to maintain the backticks and disable string expansion.